# $\left(-1\right)^3=(-1)^{6\cdot1/2}=\left((-1)^{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sure there is something wrong here, but I just don't see find which step I'm not allowed to take:

$$\left(-1\right)^3=(-1)^{6\cdot \frac{1}{2}}=\left((-1)^{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{1}=1$$

Comment: similar discussion here which in essence explains that rules of exponents cannot be blindly stretched into negatives bases: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1881811/why-is-x-1-frac1x?noredirect=1#comment3857477_1881811

Comment: Actually, that discussion is primarily about negative exponents, not negative bases. For negative bases and positive integer powers, the definition is pretty clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step you're not allowed to take is 
$$(-1)^{6 \cdot \frac{1}{2}} = ((-1)^6)^ \frac{1}{2}$$

The theorem that you're trying to apply -- that
$$
a^{b \cdot c} = (a^b)^c
$$
is true for integers $b$ and $c$ and nonnegative $a$. But it's not generally true for non-integer values, in particular because the notation $a^\frac{1}{2}$ is not well defined (it can mean either $\sqrt{a}$ or $-\sqrt{a}$).

Comment: I would say it was true for non-integers when they are all positive reals

Comment: That claim is certainly true. But the theorem in the OPs precalculus text almost certainly doesn't claim that (or prove it -- how could they without a definition of $a^b$ for $b$ non-rational, which requires calculus to do right?) instead OP's book probably states (and maybe proves) the integer version, so it was that version that I cited.